# Script to Reboot on a Live USB

Tags: powershell

Good morning to all

I have a user who wants to use a live usb for certain things. I am trying to find a way (write a script) that when the user runs it, it will reboot the pc either at the boot menu to choose to boot with the usb or even better boot straight to the live usb. The user has a win 10 pc and I want to have the script on his desktop to double click it and make the pc restart.

Any help will be welcomed

Answer (score 0):

simple batch file can do that for you:

```
shutdown /r /o
```

it won't get you directly to live usb, but it will give you an option to select it (as the /o gets you into advanced boot options). You can also add "/f" to force reboot and "/t 0" if you don't want to wait 60secs - the whole command would look like this:

```
shutdown /r /o /f /t 0
```

Comment: To avoid the prompt you could change your boot order in the BIOS/UEFI to check USB connected devices first. Just remember to remove the USB before restarting the computer to get back to normal windows boot.